# Как проксировать xenforo форум через nginx

Tags: nginx

Хочу проксировать форум xenforo через nginx, но происходит редирект.
Как можно проксировать форум xenforo? Я хочу это сделать через nginx, но можно и через Apache2 или какой-то другой инструмент

Делаю так:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://xenforo.info;
        proxy_set_header Host xenforo.info;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # XenForo-specific configuration
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Но происходит редирект на оригинальный форум

Comment: Вполне логично, вы отправляете запрос на http, вот он и отвечает редиректом на https

Comment: Даже, если я отправляю запрос на форум без https на http, он все равно делает редирект

Comment: Ну так именно в этом и дело, отправлять нужно на https

Comment: Ок, если отправляю на https - все равно редирект

Comment: Почистьте кэш браузера?

Comment: А вот, теперь если отправляю на https, мне выдает 502 Bad Gateway. А как проксировать?

Comment: А читайте информацию об ошибке в логах nginx

Comment: 2023/05/11 12:27:58 [error] 18342#18342: *5 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 94.230.***.147, server: io****.us, request: "GET / HT>